# Grasping the Tangent space of Orthogonal Group

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, orthogonal-matrices, tangent-spaces

A kind of explanation was given, but I'm missing some fundamental points.

First of let's define the orthogonal Group again as a Manifold M:

$M = O(n) = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\vert \quad A^T\,A = \mathbb{1}\}$

or

$M = g^{-1}(0)$ with $g = A^T\,A-\mathbb{1}$

Now here comes the tricky party:

A curve $\Gamma$ is being defined where $\Gamma: (-\varepsilon,\epsilon) \to O(n)$ with $\Gamma(0) = \mathbb{1}$

Here what's $\Gamma$ doing? Drawing a curve in orthogonal matrices space?

But how's $\Gamma$ looking?

For instance $\Gamma = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos(\varphi) &-\sin(\varphi) \\ \\ \sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi)\end{array} \right) \quad \varphi \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ ?

Now there's somehow  taken the derivative of $\Gamma^T\,\Gamma = \mathbb{1}$ thus:

$(\Gamma^T\,\Gamma)'(0) = (\mathbb{1})' \quad \Rightarrow \quad (\Gamma^T)'(0)+\Gamma'(0) = 0$

which indicates  $\Gamma'(0) \in SO(n) = \{A \in O(n) \vert \quad \det(A) = 1\}$

Furthermore the tangent space $T_pM$ can be included:

$T_pM = \Gamma'(0)$ what means $T_pM \subset SO(n)$

In order to spot this do you really  have to use  $\Gamma^T\,\Gamma = \mathbb{1}$? Otherswise?

Now additionally the **redirection** should be shown.

There it is defined: $\Gamma: \mathbb{R}^1 \to O(n)$ where $\Gamma(t) = \exp(t\cdot\Gamma'(0))$

Hence $\Gamma(0) = \mathbb{1}$ and $\Gamma'(0) = \Gamma'(0)$. But what does this mean?

I don't understand the conclusion being made: $SO(n) \subset T_pM$

Logically the tangent space $T_pM$ of $O(n)$ on $p = \mathbb{1}$ being equal to:

$T_pM = SO(n)$ the special orthogonal group. But I don't see why.

Comment: Are you aware of the connection with antisymmetric matrices like in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116608) ?

Comment: It comes together. However it's not mentioned how the matrix exponential comes into play. I don't see why those 2 properties [$\Gamma(0) = \mathbb{1}$ and $\Gamma'(0) = \Gamma'(0)$ of $\Gamma(t) = \exp(t\cdot \Gamma'(0)$] automatically mean that $SO(n) \subset T_pM$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2778329).